# How to make Listview.builder start from the current day in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Hello guys I have a Listview.builder which display the week days, and I want to make this listview.builder start always from the current days which is highlighted.
This is my Code:

```
ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: 7,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
                    int milliseconds = now.millisecondsSinceEpoch -
                        (now.weekday - 1) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 +
                        weekIndex * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 +
                        index * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
                    DateTime dayDateTime =
                    DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(milliseconds);
                    int monthIndex = dayDateTime.month - 1;
                    List months = [
                      'Gennaio',
                      'Febbraio',
                      'Marzo',
                      'Aprile',
                      'Maggio',
                      'Giugno',
                      'Luglio',
                      'Agosto',
                      'Settembre',
                      'Ottobre',
                      'Novembre',
                      'Dicembre'
                    ];
                    List weekdays = [
                      'Lunedì',
                      'Martedì',
                      'Mercoledì',
                      'Giovedì',
                      'Venerdì',
                      'Sabato',
                      'Domenica'
                    ];
                    String month = months[monthIndex];
                    String day = dayDateTime.day.toString();
                    String weekday = weekdays[dayDateTime.weekday - 1];
                    String date = weekday + ' ' + day + ' ' + month;
                    return Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: 50,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.50,
                              child: Card(
                                color: now.weekday == index + 1 && weekIndex == 0 ? Colors.orange[900]: Colors.orange,
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    date,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 13, color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
```

as you can see the current days is controlled by `now.weekday == index + 1 && weekIndex == 0`

I guess I need to add a controller to Listviewbuilder to achieve my purpose but I dont know how to do.
And I need also to consider when is Sunday it remaine just one day in the list.
Any Input?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `add` method for `dateTime` that gets a `Duration`.

Hope below code helps you:

```dart
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
dateTime.add(Duration(days: index));
//
//
String month = months[dateTime.month - 1];
String day = dateTime.day.toString();
String weekday = weekdays[dateTime.weekday - 1];
String date = weekday + ' ' + day + ' ' + month;
//
//
color: index == 0 ? Colors.orange[900]: Colors.orange,
```

Comment: ok but the question is how to get in Listview.builder as first item of the list the current day?

Comment: the 0 `index` is your current day, we add duration to current day by it's index. Am I wrong?

Comment: then you mean to add scroll Controller and as ```initialScrollOffset``` use ```0``` ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [indexed_list_view](https://pub.dev/packages/indexed_list_view) package

*Similar to a ListView, but lets you programmatically jump to any item, by index. The index jump happens instantly, no matter if you have millions of items.*